# Making two data points in one variable one color while the rest are another color

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale-color-manual

I have a dataset of acoustic receiver locations and want to highlight two of them on the map I am making. I would like two of them to be red, while all others are black. Here's my code:

```
geom_point(aes(x = receivers$long, y = receivers$Lat, color = receivers$Mooring), 
           data = receivers)+
scale_color_manual(values = c("TRF1" = "red", "TRF3" = "red"))
```

The error I get is:

```
Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 36 needed but only 2 provided.
```

Is there any easy way to say "these two red, all others black" in R or will I have to create a separate vector specifying all the values?

Thank you!

Comment: As a quick shot in the dark, you may want to try `ggplot() + geom_point(data = receivers, aes(x = long, y = lat, color = ifelse(Mooring %in% c("TFF1", "TRF3"), "red", "black"))) + scale_color_identity()`. But you should really provide a sample of your dataset in order to get more specific help...

Comment: It is important that you understand how ggplot2 works. In fact, scale_color_manual() is referred to the color aesthetic.